# R: count times per column a condition is met and row names appear in a list

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe with count information (df1)

| rownames | sample1 | sample2 | sample3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| m1 | 0 | 5 | 1 |
| m2 | 1 | 7 | 5 |
| m3 | 6 | 2 | 0 |
| m4 | 3 | 1 | 0 |

and a second with sample information (df2)

| rownames | batch | total count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sample1 | a | 10 |
| sample2 | b | 15 |
| sample3 | a | 6 |

I also have two lists with information about the m values (could easily be turned into another data frame if necessary but I would rather not add to the count information as it is quite large). No patterns (such as even and odd) exist, I am just using a very simplistic example

`x <- c("m1", "m3")` and `y <- c("m2", "m4")`

What I would like to do is add another two columns to the sample information. This is a count of each m per sample that has a value of above 5 and appears in list x or y

| rownames | batch | total count | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sample1 | a | 10 | 1 | 0 |
| sample2 | b | 15 | 1 | 1 |
| sample3 | a | 6 | 0 | 1 |

My current strategy is to make a list of values for both x and y and then append them to df2. Here are my attempts so far:

`numX <- colSums(df1[sum(rownames(df1)>10 %in% x),])` and `numX <- colSums(df1[sum(rownames(df1)>10 %in% x),])` both return a list of 0s

`numX <- colSums(df1[rownames(df1)>10 %in% x,])` returns a list of the sum of count values meeting the conditions for each column

`numX <- length(df1[rownames(df1)>10 %in% novel,])` returns the number of times the condition is met (in this example 2L)

I am not really sure how to approach this so I have just been throwing around attempts. I've tried looking for answers but maybe I am just struggling to find the proper wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may do this with `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>% 
   rowwise %>%
    mutate(x = +(sum(df1[[rownames]][df1$rownames %in% x]) >= 5), 
           y = +(sum(df1[[rownames]][df1$rownames %in% y]) >= 5)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  rownames batch totalcount     x     y
  <chr>    <chr>      <int> <int> <int>
1 sample1  a             10     1     0
2 sample2  b             15     1     1
3 sample3  a              6     0     1
```

---

Or based on the data, a `base R` option would be

```
out <- aggregate(. ~ grp, FUN = sum, 
     transform(df1,  grp = c('x', 'y')[1 + (rownames %in% y)] )[-1])
df2[out$grp] <- +(t(out[-1]) >= 5)
```

-output

```
> df2
  rownames batch totalcount x y
1  sample1     a         10 1 0
2  sample2     b         15 1 1
3  sample3     a          6 0 1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(rownames = c("m1", "m2", "m3", "m4"), sample1 = c(0L, 
1L, 6L, 3L), sample2 = c(5L, 7L, 2L, 1L), sample3 = c(1L, 5L, 
0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <- structure(list(rownames = c("sample1", "sample2", "sample3"), 
    batch = c("a", "b", "a"), totalcount = c(10L, 15L, 6L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: When I run this (using your data input code) it adds the columns but the values are all 0

Comment: @keenan I checked it again, by copy/pasteing the data and code.  It still gives the same output.  Is there any way you have loaded other packages that masked the `mutate` or other functions

Comment: @keenan BTW, I used `x <- c("m1", "m3")` and `y <- c("m2", "m4")` from your post

Comment: I was able to make this work by using `dplyr::rowise()`

Comment: I think you loaded `slider` which have a `rowwise`

Answer (score 1):

How about using using `dplyr` and `reshape2::melt`

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
  melt %>%
  filter(value >= 5) %>% 
  mutate(x = as.numeric(rownames %in% c("m1", "m3")),
         y = as.numeric(rownames %in% c("m2", "m4"))) %>%
  select(-rownames, - value) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(x = sum(x), y = sum(y))

df2 %>% left_join(df3, by = c("rownames" = "variable"))

  rownames batch total_count x y
1  sample1     a          10 1 0
2  sample2     b          15 1 1
3  sample3     a           6 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a named list of vectors and for each `rownames` count how many values of `x` and `y` in the respective `sample` is `>= 5`.

Base R option -

```
list_vec <- list(x = x, y = y)

cbind(df2, do.call(rbind, lapply(df2$rownames, function(x) 
  sapply(list_vec, function(y) {
    sum(df1[[x]][df1$rownames %in% y] >= 5)
}))))

#  rownames batch total.count x y
#1  sample1     a          10 1 0
#2  sample2     b          15 1 1
#3  sample3     a           6 0 1
```

Using `tidyverse` -

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list_vec <- lst(x, y)

df2 %>%
  bind_cols(map_df(df2$rownames, function(x) 
    map(list_vec, ~sum(df1[[x]][df1$rownames %in% .x] >= 5))))
```

Comment: The first gives the error `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 0` and the second `Error: Can't recycle ..1 (size 3) to match ..2 (size 0).`

Comment: I don't get any such error on the data you have shared. Share your data with `dput` so that we can reproduce the error and provide a fix accordingly.